# What is the difference between Webpack resolve.aliasFields and resolve.mainFields?

Tags: javascript, webpack

The documentation around [`resolve.aliasFields`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealiasfields) is not clear and after playing around with it, this field doesn't seem to have any effect on the generated bundle.

So, when to use `resolve.aliasFielsd` option? And, does it have any relation to `resolve.mainFields`?

Comment: Did you figure anything out?

Comment: @smilebomb Nope. Still clueless...